# Does useState not call a rerender when working with object states?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, render, react-hooks

I have a `firebase` project with a `firestore` `database` `document` that looks like this.

```
document-id => 
    item1 => {detail: "value", title: "value", image: "value}
    item2 => {detail: "value", title: "value", image: "value}
    ...
```

My `React component` that renders this looks something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  firebase.getDocument("path-to-document").then(section => {
    if (section) {
      setPanels(section.data());
    }
  });
}, []);

const handleChange = (id, data) => {
  const payload = data;
  payload[id] = { ...panels[id], ...data };
  setData(payload);
}

return (<div>
  {Object.keys(data).map((key) => <Card
    data={data[key]}
    onChange={handleChange} />)}
</div>);
```

I have removed extra code from this, but the `Card` component simple sets the layout for the individual objects. On change it calls the `handleChange` function correctly and the `data State` is correctly updated to the new values (calling `console.log(data)` after the `setData` method call shows this). However the `component` does not `reRender` with the new values for `data`.

Is there some way to force the component to rerender? I found elsewhere online that `React` 'bails' out of a rerender if the setData is called with the same data as is currently there i.e. no actual change would be made.

Or conversely is there another way to handle this interaction and let the `Card` component handle the persistence of data?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a copy of your **payload**: `{...payload}`:

```
const handleChange = (id, data) => {
  const payload = data;
  payload[id] = { ...panels[id], ...data };
  setData({...payload});
}
```

Because you not changing the state, your app doesn't *React* and rerenders.

Check out [Functional Updates](http://%7B%20...%20payload%20%7D) on *React Docs*.

```js
const handleChange = (id, data) => {
  const payload = data;
  payload[id] = { ...panels[id], ...data };
  setData(prevPayload => {
      console.log(prevPayload === payload)            // true
      return payload                                  // No Re-Render

      // console.log(prevPayload === { ... payload }) // false
      // return { ... payload }                       // Re-render
  );
}
```

Explore this example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6yr728lvp3).

Comment: This is correct but you should explain why that is the case.